# Oracle Grid Control Notification for Data Guard failures

Tags: oracle, oracle-grid-control

Grid Control 10.2.0.5.

Does anyone know a way to configure a Grid Control notification rule for a failure of the SQL APPLY process on a logical standby database? I'd really like an email notification that the SQL APPLY process has encountered an error and is no longer applying redo to the logical standby.

I can get notifications on job failures, database down, listener stops, agent stops monitoring, but don't see how to get notified for this event.

Comment: I know there's got to be a way, but my brain is too fuzzy to really think it through. If there isn't an in-built method, there's no reason to think that you couldn't do a little shell script to grep the logs and return a warning that way (I did that once w/ grid. It's not too hard to do -- you have to return a number and then you assign a metric to it so that a certain number fires off an email). That said, I can't believe there isn't an in-built metric that would catch this.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. If nothing else surfaces, I'll try this out. I'd have to rotate the alert log whenever I got the error to avoid repeat notifications... Perhaps you should consider making the comment an answer so I can at least upvote it, and perhaps accept it ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Apply Lag](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14230/gui.htm#DGBKR470) will notify you when the apply is slow, not just when it has stopped.  This may give you too many notifications, but it seems like you could tweak the threshold to limit these.

See also:
[Oracle® Data Guard Concepts and Administration 10g Release 2 (10.2)](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14239/whatsnew.htm#SBYDB00000)
[Oracle® Data Guard Broker 10g Release 2 (10.2)](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14230/gui.htm#DGBKR475)

[image: (Apply Lag in Grid Control Image)]

Comment: +1, Thanks Leigh, I will check this out. Sounds promising.

Comment: It appears that the apply lag metric is not something you can trigger notifications for - at least I don't see anything in Grid Control to let me do that. The only value that looks to be helpful is the Data Guard Status metric, and I've set that to notify me in case of problems. I *think* that should do it.

Comment: And, today, I got notification that Data Guard was having trouble, so this has solved my problem. Thanks Leigh and Kerri for your help.